# Spring cloud gateway not routing web-socket based requests

Tags: spring-websocket, spring-cloud-gateway

In order to add a route for a websocket based micro-service I have
Configured my application as per [Spring cloud gateway documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#the-websocket-routing-filter)

```
  - id: sample_service_web_socket_handshake_url
    uri: lb:ws://sample-service
    predicates:
    - Path=/notification-service-ws/**
```

above **notification-service-ws** is the handshake url of websocket-service

upon accessing this websocket endpoint directly( without spring-cloud-gateway ) session has been connected with no issue

but upon trying to connect using spring-cloud-gateway the gateway gives following warning log

```
2020-01-09 10:44:02.923  WARN 5155 --- [-server-epoll-5] .a.w.r.e.DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler : Failed to handle request [GET http://192.168.10.44:4260/notification-service-ws]: Response status 400 with reason "Invalid 'Upgrade' header: {Sec-WebSocket-Version=[13], Sec-WebSocket-Key=[0EJxcMdBmRhZ5suS/INKnQ==], Sec-WebSocket-Extensions=[permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits], Host=[192.168.10.44:4260]}"
```

I have verified no HTTP request is being sent to websocket service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue resolved after adding following properties to **spring-cloud-gateway** application.yml file:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: burraq-api-gateway
  profiles:
    active: dev
  cloud:
    gateway:
      filter:
        remove-non-proxy-headers:
          headers:
          - Proxy-Authenticate
          - Proxy-Authorization
          - Keep-Alive
          - TE
          - Trailer
          - Transfer-Encoding
```

This issue occurred because spring cloud gateway by default request headers as mentioned [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#the-removehopbyhopheadersfilter-gatewayfilter-factory)